# Proving $|\vec p \cdot \vec q| \leq (\sum_{j=1}^n |p_j q_j|^{\frac{2}{3}})^\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{j=1}^n|p_j q_j|^{\frac{4}{3}})^{\frac {1}{2}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$\vec p$ and $\vec q$ is real vector.

One theorem says that $|\vec p \cdot \vec q| \leq (\sum_{j=1}^n |p_j q_j|^{\frac{2}{3}})^\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{j=1}^n|p_j q_j|^{\frac{4}{3}})^{\frac {1}{2}}$ where p_j and q_j refers to the component of each vector.

What would be the steps required to prove this? (|  | refers to absolute sign.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy Schwarz inequality, we have

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n |p_j q_j|^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n|p_j q_j|^{\frac{4}{3}}\right) \ge \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |p_j q_j|\right)^2 \ge \vert\sum_{j=1}^n p_j q_j \vert^2 = |\vec p \cdot \vec q|^2$$

Taking square roots, you have your answer.

Comment: Question: as far as I know, Cauchy-Schwarz has 2 as exponent inside two brackets on the left side of inequality... How can you use Cauchy Schwarz to do this?

Comment: Consider it as $(|p_j q_j|^\frac{1}{3})^2$ and $(|p_j q_j|^\frac{2}{3})^2$ etc.  We should be able to consider the term inside the bracket as squares - i.e. not negative, rest follows.  So CS inequality is quite general in application.